# SSH tunnel via multiple hops

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, socks, tunnel

i have 1 client (Windows OS) and 4 VPS (Linux OS) .

i want create Socks v5 proxy with ssh tunnel for connect client to VPS-4 .

client -> VPS-1 -> VPS-2 -> VPS-3 -> VPS-4 -> internet

in client with CMD i connect to VPS-1 with command :

```
ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-1-IPaddress
```

inside VPS-1 ssh window : for connect VPS-1 to VPS-2 i use command

```
ssh -Dlocalhost:9999 root@VPS-2-IPaddress
```

and inside VPS-2 ssh window : for connect VPS-2 to VPS-3 i use command

```
ssh -Dlocalhost:9999 root@VPS-3-IPaddress
```

and inside VPS-3 ssh window : for connect VPS-3 to VPS-4 i use command

```
ssh -Dlocalhost:9999 root@VPS-4-IPaddress
```

when i set "localhost" and port "9999" in browser proxy setting and open website whatismyipaddress
i see  VPS-2 IP address .

i must see VPS-4 IP address . i don't know what is problem .

anyone can advise me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much manual work.

When using a ~/.ssh/config file

```
HOST VPS-4-IPaddress
  user root
  ProxyJump VPS-3-IPaddress

HOST VPS-3-IPaddress
  user root
  ProxyJump VPS-2-IPaddress

HOST VPS-2-IPaddress
  user root
  ProxyJump VPS-1-IPaddress

HOST VPS-1-IPaddress
  user root
  ProxyJump VPS-2-IPaddress
```

It's also possible to chain the proxies in one line

```
HOST VPS-4-IPaddress
  user root
  ProxyJump VPS-1-IPaddress,VPS-2-IPaddress,VPS-3-IPaddress
```

Then you can use

```
ssh -D9999 root@VPS-4-IPaddress
```

Or without a .ssh/config file, directly on the command line (`-J` is equal to `-o ProxyJump=`)

```
ssh -D9999 VPS-4-IPaddress -J VPS-1-IPaddress,VPS-2-IPaddress,VPS-3-IPaddress
```

**The manual way**

You need to build local forwards from one machine to the next one.
The socks proxy will only be defined on the last one.

> Client:> ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-1-IPaddress
>
> VPS-1:> ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-2-IPaddress
>
> VPS-2:> ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-3-IPaddress
>
> VPS-3:> ssh -D9999 root@VPS-4-IPaddress

But the tunnel is more or less the same like the automatic variant.

Comment: yes Too much manual work. but i need method like for me . do you know what is my method problem ?

Comment: @miki I add a description for your manual way.

Comment: ty for answer , i use this command in one line :
ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-1_IP -t ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-2_IP -t ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-3_IP -t ssh -L9999:localhost:9999 root@VPS-4_IP -t ssh  -Dlocalhost:9999 root@VPS-5_IP
after this command i enter one by one VPS passwords . Can I enter passwords in the above command?

Comment: @miki  You should use a public/private key instead, then you don't need to enter a password

Comment: OK thanks . Is it possible my method  or should I use public/private key ?

Comment: @miki You could use multiple passwords, but that would be horrible. In that case you could try a tool like `expect`, With a public key, you don't need any passwords at all. Btw Using `-tt` is only necessary when using a really old `ssh` client and should be avoided, else each proxy is able to see or manipulate the traffic

Comment: thanks @jeb all method is work , but i have a problem , some time after few minute or some times after one hours , ... i see error :  "open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" . after this i must close terminal page and again start begin , do you have any solution ?